# Monad instance for simple language GADT

Tags: haskell, monads, gadt

I have the following GADT that represents a simple language of booleans and
integers.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Example1 where

import Control.Monad (ap)

data Expr t a where
  Lit :: t -> Expr t a
  Var :: a -> Expr t a
  Add :: Expr Int a -> Expr Int a -> Expr Int a
  Cmp :: Expr Int a -> Expr Int a -> Expr Bool a

instance Functor (Expr t) where
  fmap f (Lit t) = Lit t
  fmap f (Var v) = Var $ f v
  fmap f (Add e1 e2) = Add (fmap f e1) (fmap f e2)
  fmap f (Cmp e1 e2) = Cmp (fmap f e1) (fmap f e2)

instance Applicative (Expr t) where
  pure  = Var
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (Expr t) where
  return = Var
  (Lit t) >>= f = Lit t
  (Var v) >>= f = f v
  (Add e1 e2) >>= f = Add (e1 >>= f) (e2 >>= f)
  (Cmp e1 e2) >>= f = Cmp (e1 >>= f) (e2 >>= f)
```

The problem is that the las definition of bind is not satisfactory due to the type of t. Actually ghc complains with the following errors (one for each component of Cmp):

```
example1.hs:26:46:
Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘Int’
Expected type: a -> Expr Int b
  Actual type: a -> Expr t b
In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘f’
In the second argument of ‘Cmp’, namely ‘(e2 >>= f)’
```

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Your type does not have a monad instance, but you can write a similair function to bind whose type is `Expr t a -> (forall q . a -> Expr q b) -> Expr t b `. Then, the only things you can put in the "bind" are things that "don't care" about the `t` - which is `Lit` and `Var`.